# Squid - Check header before send the request

Tags: proxy, squid

This is my first time using Squid. I want to remove the information in the `headers` request that I'm using a proxy, because the site is blocking me. After I build the squid with `--enable-http-violation` following [this tutorial](https://www.metahackers.pro/spoof-http-header-using-squid-proxy/) I still getting blocked. I want to know if there is anyway to see what are the request headers before sending it or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try answers from [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/241918/how-can-i-prevent-squid-from-being-detected) to hide squid presence from http headers. Then you can use some tool which shows your http headers visible to external sites ([this tool](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending) for example) to check that you succeeded in removing all "bad" headers.